# clang: error: no such file or directory: ...PrecompiledHeaders..../...pch

Tags: xcode, clang, precompiled-headers

I have a project building correctly in one machine, but i am getting the following error when i try to build it in another.  Both machines have the same version of OS X and XCode, and exactly the same source files.

clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/Cristian/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MadGoose-alcvoermelusildxepcbneygiwbk/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/MadGoose_Prefix-afbukpnsoecegqeiiuwhfersynbx/MadGoose_Prefix.pch'

I have the following files on that directory

- MadGoose_Prefix.pch.data
- MadGoose_Prefix.pch.pch
- MadGoose_Prefix.pch.dia
- MadGoose_Prefix.pch.pch.hash-criteria

Anyone knows what could it be?
Or what should i compare between the machines?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, i had this in the Build Settings

```
FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS = (
                "$(inherited)",
                "\"${FACEBOOKSDK}\"",
            );
```

Since we don't use Facebook on the project anymore the variable `${FACEBOOKSDK}` was empty in the machine with the problem, i remove it from there and problem solved.

An extra tip for others with build problems, check the `XCBuildConfigutation` section of the `.pbxproj` directly (Everything between `/* Begin XCBuildConfiguration section */` and `/* End XCBuildConfiguration section */`), it was easy to spot the problem there, in XCode the variables are replaced with their value unless you edit them.